# regular expresstion to match [/ , .] in ng-pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I am trying to create a expression so that input string must not contain forward slash, comma or a dot.

```
<form name="myForm">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input class="form-control"
        type="text"
        data-ng-model="model_name"
        name="modelName"
        ng-pattern="/^[\/,.]/" required> 
      <div ng-messages="myForm.$submitted && myForm.modelName.$error" role="alert">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-message="pattern">Special characters [/ , .] are not allowed.</div>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-message="required">This field is required.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The regular expression `/^[\/,.]/` properly matches all the characters inside the square brackets but the problem is that it is not allowing me to input normal strings such as abc or abc_def or any other strings. I don't have deep knowledge of regex and I am not getting any idea how to solve this problem. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Your `regex` is wrong, `^` must be inside `[]` in order to match all characters except `/.,` put them in a `[^/.,]`, in regex, when using `^` inside a block `[]` will match anything but what is inside the `[]`.

[image]

When testing regex, this web it useful: http://www.regexpal.com/

Comment: your solution works. I had use a + after square bracket and removed g. I tested this pattern here [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern] I don't know why it's not working for me. I also changed `myForm.modelName.$error` to `myForm.modelName.$valid`.

Comment: `ng-pattern = "/[^\/,.]+/"` was not working so I created `$scope.regex = "[^\/,.]+"` and wrote `ng-pattern = "regex"` and it worked. Do you have any thoughts about that?

Comment: I am not familiar with angular, sorry. May be you need to specify that the patter is going to be a with `ng-pattern = "regex"`